# Flutter with FirebaseAppDistribution ignore "--target"

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradlew, firebase-app-distribution

**Updated (07 Nov 2019)**

I've tried the following command and it works as expected
Assume that `flavor`=`Staging` and `build`=`Release`, `Build_Variant`=`StagingRelease`.
And based on `Flutter` entry point file `(--target)`=`lib/main_stg.dart`

```
./gradlew appDistributionUploadStagingRelease --project-prop target=lib/main_stg.dart
```

It seems like `appDistributionUploadStagingRelease` re-build apk even though `assembleStagingRelease` is not added in the command.

**Issue**

I've a project which contain the following flavors and targets

```
Flavors
- Dev
- Staging
- Production

Targets (<project_root/lib>)
- main_dev.dart (development)
- main_stg.dart (staging)
- main.dart     (production)
```

I've been using this command 
`flutter build --release --target staging --t lib/main_stg.dart` for building Staging.

However, when executing FirebaseAppDistribution using `./gradlew appDistributionStagingRelease`, the uploaded APK ignore `lib/main_stg.dart` and use `lib/main.dart`.

Further check on the log indicate that it does not rebuild

```
> Task :app:appDistributionUploadStagingRelease
Found APK at <project_root>/build/app/outputs/apk/staging/release/app-staging-release.apk.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...
Getting appId from output of google services plugin
This APK has not been uploaded before.
Uploading the APK.
Uploaded APK successfully 202
No release notes passed in. Skipping this step.
Added testers/groups successfully 200
App Distribution upload finished successfully!
```

Does any `Flutter` dev encounter similar issue? Kindly guide me for this.

Thank You

Comment: I have come across same issue. Do you find any solution?

Comment: Hi karn, the solution is “ ./gradlew appDistributionUploadStagingRelease --project-prop target=lib/main_stg.dart”. Under the updated 07 Nov 2019. The solution is based on my build variant “Staging”.